# dead code in java game with player

Tags: java

I have a game in which two players take turns to guess a number that has been randomly generated. I'm using methods to control the player turns as follows:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class randomnumgame {

private static final int player1lives = 4;
private static final int player2lives = 4;
public static void main(String []args){
    while( player1lives > 0  &&  player2lives > 0){
        playerturn1();
        playerturn2();
    if (player1lives == 0 || player2lives == 0){
        game();
    }
}
}
public static void playerturn2() {
    int lives = player2lives;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int random = rand.nextInt(250) + 1;
    String player2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ("Please enter a number between 1 and 250, Player 2.");
    int player2int = Integer.parseInt(player2);
    if(player2int == random){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 has guessed correctly. You have " +lives+ " lives left");
    }
    lives--;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your guess was wrong. The actual number was: " +random+ " You have " +lives+ " left" );
    }       
public static void playerturn1() {
    int lives = player1lives;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int random = rand.nextInt(250) + 1;
    String player1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ("Please enter a number between 1 and 250, Player 1.");
    int player1int = Integer.parseInt(player1);
    if(player1int == random){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 has guessed correctly. You have " +lives+ " lives left");
    }
    lives--;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your guess was wrong. The actual number was: " +random+ " You have " +lives+ " lives left");
    }
private static void game(){
    if(player1lives == 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 has won the game.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if(player2lives == 0 ){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 has won the game.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that this code is marked as dead code in Eclipse:

```
    if (player1lives == 0 || player2lives == 0){
    game();
}
```

And:

```
  private static void game(){
    if(player1lives == 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 has won the game.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if(player2lives == 0 ){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 has won the game.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

I've found similar questions but can't apply them to this specific application. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: read about java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase. So do variable names!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`player1lives` and `player2lives` are `final`, so they never can be changed. They are set up to `value = 4`, that means that they never could be equal to 0.

Here:

```
int lives = player2lives;
lives--;
```

You are changing a lives value. It will not affect `player2lives` value.

You should change your declaration to:

```
private static int player1lives = 4;
```

and then there will be no need for lives variable :

```
player1lives--;
```